# Improving awkward wiring

Tags: wiring, data-wiring, ethernet, coaxial-cable

I just had FIOS installed today to replace Comcast. Everything went great but I didn't pay attention to how they installed the connector to my router. I thought they would add a port for the Ethernet right next to the cable, but instead the Ethernet cable is routed out from behind the faceplate awkwardly.

Is this what I need? [Amazon back-plate product with coax and cat-6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07B9RNX5F)

I am not sure if that back-plate would connect to the left-side of that Ethernet connection. What is that called?

[image]
[image]

Result: [image]

Much better than before. It was really jammed up behind the faceplate, so I couldn't keep the coax connected. I think I need to cut out a bigger hole and get a bigger faceplate for that. At least for now the look is improved. Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: Wow, that is a shoddy job!  Thanks for the warning to everyone that you need to watch 'em like a hawk during the install.

Comment: if you are stating that the ethernet socket on the left is popping out of the retaining bracket, then a new combination back plate is not necessary going to fix the problem.  Even if it popped out of the retaining bracket/hole, your ethernet cable would still be plugged in.  Maybe a picture of of what you mean by popping out would help understand what the issue is.

Comment: I do not follow you Programmer66. By popping out I mean that the wire that is behind the coaxial back-plate. I want to substitute that by hiding the wire and installing a back-plate with coax and Ethernet connections.

Comment: Popping out to me means  "coming loose".  What you really mean is that you don't like how the wire is routed.  The cover removed in the ethernet box provides no clarify.  Yes, you would  use a combo coaxial/ethernet faceplate (no back plane needed) and rewire the ethernet wires to the ethernet outlet provided in the new combo faceplate. Or if you're lucky use the existing ethernet outlet

Comment: Thanks for explaining the precise meaning of popping out, I see what you mean now. I ordered the back-plate and as seen above and I will hopefully be able to get it to work as expected.

Comment: Once new combo faceplate is installed, the module to the right is no longer needed.  You would just plug the router directly to the ethernet on the new combo faceplate.

Comment: Careful anytime you see "Sold by <somebody else> and Fulfilled by Amazon".  98% of the time it is cheap Cheese junk.  Looks good, performs terribly.  And they fake the reviews too, they're very good at that. I call that one "Ikeaguy", has thousands of seller names that sound like items from an Ikea catalog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left-hand part of the Ethernet connection is commonly called a keystone jack or a keystone module. All brands look more-or-less the same, but (to my knowledge) there isn't any formal industry standardization on the dimensions. One can rest assured that Leviton jacks will fit nicely into Leviton brand wall plates, but a Leviton brand jack might not fit so well into an unbranded wall plate from Amazon (purely as an example -- I can't tell from the photo what brand of jack it is).

You can try a wall plate such as the one linked. There's a fair chance the existing jack will fit well enough. If it doesn't, you can try again with another brand of wall plate or buy a jack and plate that are known to work together and replace the existing jack.